# How to get image URL from drag &drop if the image is a link?

Tags: image, url, drag-and-drop

I have found a lot of various implementations of drag and drop but all of them seemed to operate under the general assumption of images not being nested inside an < a href > tag.

Whether it is a browser, mac os or windows the result is always the same:

- Dragging an

  `< img src='http://www.lol.com/pic.jpg' />`

will input `http://www.lol.com/pic.jpg` in an html form. OR if dragged into the desktop - it will save the actual image.

- Dragging an

  `< a href='http://www.lol.com/notgonnahappen.html'>< img src='http://www.lol.com/pic.jpg' />< /a>`

will input `http://www.lol.com/notgonnahappen.html` and create a URL link if dragged on the desktop.

Is there anyway to extract the image URL? And not that of the link it is associated with? JS? Java? C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));
var img = data.attr('src');
if (!img) 
    img = data.find("img").attr('src');
```

Comment: e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html') only seems to work in Chrome.<br>
FF fails with external images, and IE fails completely.

Answer (score 0):

With pure Javascript you can try this:

```
function drop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault(); 
    var imageUrl = evt.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    var rex = /src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*/;
    var url, res;
    url = rex.exec(imageUrl);
    alert(url[1]);
}
```

And here is a working [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4E92W/6/)